# Absolute Value in Random Numbers Generator

Tags: java, numbers, generator

I am trying to create a random phone number generator. The code below works but the output is negative numbers. How do I make it positive? Should I use the absolute function? And how do I make it more random?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandPhone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ( "Generating a random string of numerals for Human communication system.");

         Random generator = new Random(1234567890);

         int r = generator.nextInt()*-1;

         System.out.println ( r);
    }
}
```

Comment: And why are you multiplying the `generator.nextInt()` by -1? No wonder the resulting integers are negative.

Answer (score 3):

> Random(long seed)
>             Creates a new random number generator using a single long seed.

You're seeding it at each start. Don't seed it, but let it seed itself. That should give you new pseudorandom values each time.

You can limit to positive integers like so:

```
 int r = generator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```